# How to generate all the possible permutations based on a quota?

Tags: python, combinations, permutation, python-itertools

Given two lists `X` and `Y`:

`X = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']`

`Y = ['I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N']`

How to create all the possible sets of 4 combinations with the restriction of considering at least 2 elements of `X` and `Y`. For example, a valid combination would look like this:

```
[('A', 'J', 'M', 'D'), ..., ('I', 'M', 'B', 'C')]
```

The reason is that it contains 2 elements from `X` and `Y`. The combination `[('A', 'B', 'M', 'D')]` is not valid because it containes 3 elements from X and 1 from Y. So far I tried to:

```
import itertools
set(list(itertools.permutations([e for e in zip(X, Y)])))
```

However, this violates the quota restriction. What is the correct way of implementing the quota permutation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to do permutations of 2 from each list and combine them, then do all the combinations of each set of 4:

```
from itertools import permutations, combinations
X = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']
Y = ['I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N']

x = (n+m for n in permutations(X,2) for m in permutations(Y,2))
for i in x:
    print(list(combinations(i,4)))
```